# Dragging Angular UI modal with title bar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/M9WNRyeLa5ufzwbmmQpl?p=preview) I have an Angular UI Modal with a title bar. The objective is to drag the entire modal by dragging the title bar. Both the title bar and the modal share the (top,left) position, as the modal is a rectangle (I changed the radius to zero), but when I drag the title bar it doesn't work. Any ideas?

HTML

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctl">

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="topbar">This is the title</div>

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>

   </body>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("ctl", function($scope,$uibModal,$timeout) {


  var modalInstance;
  $scope.open = function () {
    modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: false,
          windowClass: 'the-modal',
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'
        });

        $timeout(function(){
            $('.topbar').draggable({
                drag: function( event, ui ) {
                        $( ".modal-content" ).offset({ 
                                        top: ui.position.top,
                                        left: ui.position.left});
                }   
            });

        },10);

    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.modal-content').draggable({
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
    if(event.toElement.className.indexOf("topbar") == -1 ) return false;
  }
});
```

Try with above code instead of making 'topbar' draggable make the 'modal' draggable only when it dragged by clicking the 'topbar'.

Comment: This works, the only detail is that if you drag fast up and down the cursor loses the bar focus and the drag ends.